# Operators on Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Question:** *Consider $A \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space. Show that $\|A\|=\sup_{u,v \neq 0} \frac{|\langle u,Av \rangle|}{\|u\|\|v\|}$.*

**Remark:** Here $A$ is an operator from $\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ and $\|A\|:=\sup_{\|u\|=1} \|Au\|$.

I've managed to show that $\|A\|\geq \sup_{u,v \neq 0} \frac{|\langle u,Av \rangle|}{\|u\|\|v\|}$, but I'm not sure how to prove the other direction, that is, $\|A\|\leq \sup_{u,v \neq 0} \frac{|\langle u,Av \rangle|}{\|u\|\|v\|}$. So, any help will be extremely useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By choosing $u=Av$ in the supremum,
$$\sup_{u, v \ne 0} \frac{\langle u, Av \rangle}{\|u\|\|v\|}
\ge \sup_{v \ne 0} \frac{\langle Av, Av \rangle}{\|Av\|\|v\|}
= \sup_{v \ne 0} \frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}
= \sup_{\|v\|=1} \|Av\|.$$

---

Filling in the gaps in response to Ben Grossman's comment:

For $v$ such that $Av \ne 0$, taking $u=Av$ yields
$$\sup_{u \ne 0} \frac{\langle u, Av \rangle}{\|u\|\|v\|}
\ge \frac{\langle Av, Av \rangle}{\|Av\|\|v\|}
= \frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}$$
The outer inequality
$\sup_{u \ne 0} \frac{\langle u, Av \rangle}{\|u\|\|v\|}
\ge \frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}$ also holds when $Av = 0$ since both sides are zero. Taking a supremum over $v \ne 0$ on both sides yields
$$\sup_{u, v \ne 0} \frac{\langle u, Av \rangle}{\|u\|\|v\|}
\ge \sup_{v \ne 0} \frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|} = \sup_{\|v\|=1} \|Av\|.$$

Comment: Note: this requires that $Av \neq 0$